# Special character in Borland c++ Builder

Tags: unicode, utf-8, c++builder, borland-c++

I just wanna use Delta sign "Δ" in Borland c++ Builder 5.

for example in a label:

```
Label1->Caption = "delta sign here?";
```

thnx.

Comment: Just copy and paste it!

Comment: ouu really? it s not working of course i tried it

Comment: The ∆ character is only available in the Unicode set. C++Builder 5 is not unicode-enabled, so I don't think you will be able to use it directly there. I can copy & paste it without problems into a C++Builder XE5 form. If using a newer version of C++Builder is not an option, you might try with some 3rd party libraries, for instance, TMS has one (https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsuni.asp) but it's only for C++Builder 6 and up.

Answer (score 2):

C++Builder 5 uses an ANSI-based VCL and ANSI-based Win32 API calls, where the ANSI encoding is dictated by the active user's locale settings in Windows.

If your app is running on a Greek machine that uses Latin-7/ISO-8859-7 (Windows codepage 28597) as its native locale, or at least has Greek fonts installed, you should be able to set the `Label1->Font->Charset` to `GREEK_CHARSET` (161) and `Label1->Font->Name` to a Greek font, and then assign the Delta character like this:

```
// using an implicit conversion from Unicode
// to ANSI on a Greek-locale machine...
Label1->Caption = L"Δ";
Label1->Caption = L"\x0394";
Label1->Caption = (wchar_t) 0x0394;
Label1->Caption = (wchar_t) 916;
```

Or:

```
// using an explicit Greek ANSI codeunit
// on a Greek font machine...
Label1->Caption = (char) 0xC4;
Label1->Caption = (char) 196;
```

However, if you need to display the Delta character on a non-Greek machine, or at least one that does not have any Greek fonts installed, you will have to use a third-party Unicode-enabled Label component, such as from the old TNTWare component suite, so that you can use Unicode codepoint U+0394 directly, eg:

```
TntLabel1->Caption = L"Δ";
TntLabel1->Caption = L"\x0394";
TntLabel1->Caption = (wchar_t) 0x0394;
TntLabel1->Caption = (wchar_t) 916;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows:

EDIT: Try ALT + 30, it works! ▲▲▲▲

Comment: it s not working ALT+916 is this "ö"
i m using turkish q keyboard

Comment: I'm using a spanish one

Comment: I've just edited my answer with the correct one, please try it

Comment: ▲ this is not Δ 
and also in borland it comes ^ this bro.

Comment: thanks bro it s really complicated i could nt undrstand :(